# Where do I put the code for the like button on facebook on my facebook page?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I don't know where to put the code onto my facebook page. I have searched everywhere and no one and no site gives me a specific answer enough for me to understand.

Comment: It's your site, put it where it makes sense... ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is facebook's official page.  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

It explains all the tags and how to use them as well as a generator for whatever facebook url you might want.